# How to change the table names after "makemigrations"

Tags: python, django, database

Whenever I make migrations, Django automatically attaches the name of my application to database tables. For example, if I have application `myapp` and there is a model named `Model1`, then after migrations the database table name will be `myapp_model1`.

I don't need app name along with table name. If someone knows how to change it then please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to let Django choose the table names automatically. Having the application name as a prefix means that you can have two models with the same name in different applications, but their database table names will not clash.

If you really want to change the table name, you can use the [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#db-table) option to set the table name in the database.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mymodel'
```

This might be tricky if the database tables have already been created. To avoid problems, I would only set the `db_table` option for a new application.